# r data.frame going back dates

Tags: r, date, dataframe, calendar, rows

I have a R data.frame as below. By store, I want to create newstart and newend columns such that newstart and newend will be 14 days subtracted from respective start and end columns.

But if the newstart or newend date is either in original start or end column then I would like to go back 14 days further.

So in the case of the 3rd row, newstart and newend will be 20131120 and 20131127 respectively. But as 20131120 is present in the end column for store 8 (row 2), I have to go back 2 more weeks to get newend and newstart. I have to check again to make sure that newstart and newend are not present for store 8 in start and end columns. How could I do the same?

I have a table with multiple values for store column. I am just showing a snapshot here

```
   store=c(rep(8,4),rep(11,4))
start=c("20131009","20131113","20131204","20150624","20140820","20140924","20150923","20151014")
end=c("20131016","20131120","20131211","20150701","20140827","20141001","20150930","20151021")

maint=data.frame(store,start,end)



maint$start=as.Date(maint$start,"%Y%m%d")
maint$end=as.Date(maint$end,"%Y%m%d")
maint
  store    start      end
1     8 20131009 20131016
2     8 20131113 20131120
3     8 20131204 20131211
4     8 20150624 20150701
5    11 20140820 20140827
6    11 20140924 20141001
7    11 20150923 20150930
8    11 20151014 20151021
```

## ----------------------update1

the first answer below works. But in case of the second and third row and the last two rows, it provides overlapping dates. How can i avoid such overalap while making sure that dates in newstart and newend dont overlap with start and end column

```
  store  start  end newstart    newend

8   10/9/2013   10/16/2013  9/25/2013   10/2/2013
**8 11/13/2013  11/20/2013  10/30/2013  11/6/2013
8   12/4/2013   12/11/2013  10/23/2013  10/30/2013**
8   6/24/2015   7/1/2015    6/10/2015   6/17/2015
11  8/20/2014   8/27/2014   8/6/2014    8/13/2014
11  9/24/2014   10/1/2014   9/10/2014   9/17/2014
**11    9/23/2015   9/30/2015   9/9/2015    9/16/2015
11  10/14/2015  10/21/2015  9/2/2015    9/9/2015**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a while loop within a for loop as follows

```
# create newdate columns
maint$newstart <- as.Date(NA)
maint$newend <- as.Date(NA)

# loop over each row of maint
for(i in 1:nrow(maint)) {

  # get all start and end dates for current store
  dates_focal <- c(maint$start[maint$store == maint$store[i]],
                   maint$end[maint$store == maint$store[i]])

  # subtract 14 days from newstart and newend
  newstart <- maint$start[i] - 14
  newend <- maint$end[i] - 14

  # exit condition for following while loop
  exit_condition <- F

  # check for conflict
  # if conflict, repeatedly subtract 14 days until no more conflict
  while(!exit_condition) {

    conflict <- any(is.element(c(newstart, newend), dates_focal))

    if (conflict) {
      newstart <- newstart - 14
      newend <- newend - 14
    } else {
      exit_condition <- T
    }
  }

  # set newstart and newend
  maint$newstart[i] <- as.Date(newstart)
  maint$newend[i] <- as.Date(newend)
}
```

Note that this example doesn't check for conflicts for a given store within the newstart and newend columns. That is, a given store could have overlapping newstart and newend dates (in separate rows). Should be a quick modification if that's undesirable for your application.

## Update 1

If you also want to check the newstart and newend columns for conflict, just add these columns to dates_focal, as in:

```
dates_focal <- c(
  maint$start[maint$store == maint$store[i]],
  maint$end[maint$store == maint$store[i]],
  maint$newstart[maint$store == maint$store[i]],
  maint$newend[maint$store == maint$store[i]]
)
```

Keep in mind that this approach may yield different results if the order of rows in your maint data frame is changed, because newdates within a given row depend on newdates in previous rows.

Comment: thanks for the answer and your comment. Would it be possible to answer my update 1 which is same as what you have mentioned...